# Error 000725 message from output workspace when using Python (ArcPy) script tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, error-000725

I am having trouble running a script tool that I just created in Arc 10.1.  The script runs fine in PythonWin, but when I create a script tool with it, the tool seems to not want to accept folders or geodatabases as its output workspace.  I have the output parameter (argument) set as both an output and a workspace in the script tool, but it still keeps giving me an error that the "Dataset.....already exists"

I'm a new user, so I can't post a picture, but the error is 000725

Here is my script, if that helps out.

```
import arcpy
#allow for overwrites
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#set the workspace
inWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (0)

#set the erase feature
eraseFeature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (1)

#set the output workspace
outWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (2)


#get a list of all the features in the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = inWorkspace
featureClassList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

try:

    #loop through all of the features in the workspace
    for featureClass in featureClassList:

        #construct the output path
        outEraseFeature = outWorkspace + "\\erase_" + featureClass

        #perform erase
        arcpy.Erase_analysis(featureClass, eraseFeature, outEraseFeature)

        arcpy.AddMessage("Wrote clipped file " + outEraseFeature + ". ")
        print "Wrote clipped file " + outEraseFeature + ". "

except:

    # Report if there was an error
    arcpy.AddError("Could not erase feature classes")
    print "Could not erase feature classes"
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: If it really does already exist you can try adding `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput =True`

Answer (score 6):

I found out that if I changed the direction of the output workspace from 'output' to 'input', then the script ran without an error.

Comment: thanks a lot - this hint finally solved my problem I have been working on for hours. Within my created python script an output folder should be specified to store a bunch of raster results. Setting it to Output created errors, now as I set it to Input it immediately worked.

Answer (score 4):

It is for your own protection. To not get that error, you need to enable this option:[image: Overwrite Outputs].

Alternately, change your `Output_Workspace` to an input parameter rather than an output parameter.